# AWS Socket connection over internet using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sockets

This the server code using sockets. I have deployed in the AWS server. I am trying to access it from local machine which is outside AWS. I have opened the TCP port 10000 in the security group (custom TCP) to my local IP. But getting a error as shown below.

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()

    try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address

        # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(16)
            print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
            if data:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'sending data back to the client'
                connection.sendall(data)
            else:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
                break
            
    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close()
```

This is the client code (trial-sockets.py) i am using. The error i am getting is given below

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print(sys.stderr, 'connecting to %s port %s' % server_address)
sock.connect(server_address)

try:
    
    # Send data
    message = 'This is the message.  It will be repeated.'
    print(sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message)
    sock.sendall(message)

    # Look for the response
    amount_received = 0
    amount_expected = len(message)
    
    while amount_received < amount_expected:
        data = sock.recv(16)
        amount_received += len(data)
        print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data

finally:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
    sock.close()
```

Error Message:

```
arunachalam@LV-SL306:~/Documents/aws$ python3 trail-sockets.py 
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'> connecting to localhost port 10000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trail-sockets.py", line 10, in <module>
    sock.connect(server_address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: In the client code. I am using the public IP of my AWS to access the server

Comment: Shouldn't the server address be pointed to the AWS IP address instead of localhost?

Comment: @BurningAlcohol i have added AWS IP to the client code. Still Facing the same error

Comment: As @BurningAlcohol has mentioned, you should bind the server to either 0.0.0.0 or the IP address of your instance.